# awk to do group by sum of column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have this csv file and I am trying to write shell script to calculate sum of column after doing group by on it. Column number is 11th (STATUS)

My script is

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{arr[$11]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' $f > $parentdir/outputfile.csv;
```

File output expected is

```
COMMITTED 2
```

but actual output is just 2.

It prints only count and not group by sum. If I delete any other columns and run same query then it works fine but not with below sample data.

```
FILE NAME;SEQUENCE NR;TRANSACTION ID;RUN NUMBER;START EDITCREATION;END EDITCREATION;END COMMIT;EDIT DURATION;COMMIT DURATION;HAS DEPENDENCY;STATUS;DETAILS
Buldhana_Refinesource_FG_IW_ETS_000001.xml;1;4a032127-b20d-4fa8-9f4d-7f2999c0c08f;1;20180831130210345;20180831130429638;20180831130722406;140;173;false;COMMITTED;
Buldhana_Refinesource_FG_IW_ETS_000001.xml;2;e4043fc0-3b0a-46ec-b409-748f98ce98ad;1;20180831130722724;20180831130947144;20180831131216693;145;150;false;COMMITTED;
```

Answer (score 2):

change the `FS` to `;` in your script

```
awk -F';' 'NR>1{arr[$11]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' file

COMMITTED 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong field separator. Use

```
awk -F\;
```

`;` must be escaped to use it as a literal. Except this, your approach seems OK.

---

Besides awk, you may also use

```
tail -n +2 $f | cut -f11 -d\; | sort | uniq -c
```

or

```
datamash --header-in -t \; -g 11 count 11 < $f
```

to do the same thing.